# Tool to migrate from Embedded SQL to ODBC

Tags: sql, migration, odbc, legacy, embedded-database

I have a bunch of C code accessing database (Oracle, DB2 and Sybase) through Embedded SQL : the base code is the same, but with three different precompilers, three sort of executables are built, one for each database/platform.

I works perfectly fine, but we need now migrate to a solution using ODBC access.

The problem is : what tools / api can be used ? A direct way seems to write a custom precompiler (or modify an existent) to wrap all SQL and host variables calls to calls on an ODBC connection.

Can somebody recommend tools for that task or api to keep it simple ?

Or is it a simpler way, another approach ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is usual for such situations, there are likely no off shelf answers; people's codebases always have a number of surprise in them, and the combination prevents a COTs tool from ever being economical for individual situations.

What you want is a [program transformation system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) (PTS), with a C front end, that can be customized to parse embedded SQL.  Such tools can apply source-to-source rewrite rules ("if you see *this* pattern, then replace it by *that* pattern") to solve the problem.

These tools require some pretty technical effort to configure.  In your case, you'd have to adjust a C front end to handle embedded SQL; that's typically not in C parsers.  (How is it that you can process this stuff in its current form?)   You'll have trouble with the C preprocessor, because people do abusive things with it that really violate a parsers nested-structures-view of the universe.  Then you'll have to write and test the rules.

This effort is a sunk cost to be traded against the effort of doing the work by hand or some more ad hoc scripting (e.g., Perl) that partially does the job leaving you to clean it up.   Our experience is that it is not worth the trouble below 100K SLOC, and that you have no chance of manual/ad hoc remediation above 1M SLOC, and in between your mileage will vary.

At these intermediate sizes, you can agonize over the tradeoffs; that costs energy and time, too. Sometimes its just better to bite the bullet and do it any way you can an clean it up.

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit is one of these PTS.  It has a customizable C parser and preprocessor, precisely to help deal with these configuration troubles.  The other PTSs mentioned in the Wikipedia article, do not, I beleive, have any serious C parser associated with them.  (I'm the guy behind DMS).

Comment: Fortunately enough, the codebase (> 3 millions LOC) sticks to hard coding rules. It seems 'possible' to write a custom parser with no great cost (via antlr). I think we will hit the wall and then turn on more professional and talented guys like you. Thank you

Comment: Lots of people think writing a parser is both easy and all that is necessary.  Its not, especially for a real language like C.  And, see my essay on "Life after Parsing" http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html.  I think you have the right idea about how this kind of projects politically devolves, though.